# Enable-SPFeature : The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site level defined by the Url

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to activate a web level feature using powershell with the following command:

```
Enable-SPFeature –identity 3ad4787b-e859-432c-be22-c772725e0dbc -URL http://win-p8f03cpnjn5:5555/gateway/home/stafftravel/
```

I get the following error

*The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site level defined by the Url*

However I can see the feature in  site settings/site feature page.

This commands works well for site collection features but fails on web scope activation.

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the feature successfully on the farm before enabling it. This will remove this error.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you can see the file in 14 hive and that your using the correct guid/url!

14/Template/Features

9 times out of 10 its the wrong guid or spelt incorrectly ;) / wrong url

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the feature (solution) is really developed for Farm level scope.
If that is a WSP file, you can rename it to .cab and extract it and check the "Scope" attribute in Feature.xml.
[image]